# Marshalling simple C# struct to C++ when C++ version needs a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling, default-constructor

**This issue only happens when using the C++ dll in a Windows Store project and running it on a device. It works fine when used with Android or iOS projects.**

I have a struct in some native c++ code looking like this:

```
struct InteropVector2 {
    float32 x;
    float32 y;

    InteropVector2(float32 x, float32 y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    InteropVector2() {}
};
```

Very simple, nothing fancy. So i have created another struct in C# to use when i need to pass this struct from C# to C++ looking like this:

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct InteropVector2
{
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public InteropVector2(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Also very simple. However, when i pass this from C# to C++ the x and y values are 0.0, no matter what i pass in. **But if i remove the parameterless constructor in the C++ struct, it all works like a charm.** I need to have the parameterless constructor in the C++ code. Any ideas how i can accomplish this?

Here is an example of the usage of these structs:

C++

```
EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT bool __stdcall TestMyVector2(InteropVector2 p1) {
    LOG("[C++] Vector2: (%f %f)", p1.x, p1.y);

    return false;
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport(pluginName)]
public static extern bool TestMyVector2(InteropVector2 p1);
```

and

```
var = B2D.TestMyVector2(new InteropVector2(1.44f, 2.55f)));
```

Comment: I think is something related to pack. As a test try to shift float32 x, y; at the top of your c++ struct and add pragma pack to pack as in c#

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I moved the floats to the top of the c++ struct and added #pragma pack(4). Still the same though.

Comment: It is sure odd that removing the default constructor in C++ makes it work. Edit: Made it bold so people can focus on the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is very wierd indeed. The only thing i do is comment/uncomment the parameterless constructor. I have verified this several times since it seems so unlikely.

Comment: Oh, i should add that this only happens when using the C++ dll in a Windows Store project and running it on a device. Sorry about that, it is quite important information. I will edit the question.